# Explicit wait in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, wait

I'm using web driver wait as explicit wait in selenium web driver. But It's not consistent it seems. before mouse over operations, links It's throwing unable to locate element error. Please see the below method and suggest where am I going wrong.

```
public WebElement waitForElement(String xPathExpression) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPathExpression))));

        return element;
    }
```

Comment: You need to give us more details. The code you placed looks fine, but we can't see a locator, any of the html you are working with. We can't tell you what is wrong if we don't have anything to work with. I can assure you that there is no bug with explicit waiting in selenium.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but I might have seen similar behavior on very dynamic pages. I.e the element on the page changes while being evalued.

I'm able to workaround these kind of problems by using [`FluentWait#ignoring`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html#ignoring-java.lang.Class-%20ignoring)

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30)
       .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```